# Docker image behaves different on AWS ECR

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, artificial-intelligence, amazon-ecr

First of all, I'm rather new to Docker and I'm just beginning to grasp its core concepts, although I'm, not sure this is where the issue originates. Anyway, I'm currently working on a (python) project involving a summarization model (https://huggingface.co/sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6) which is downloaded upon building the image by running an initialization script. When building and running the container locally, I can see that the pre-trained model is being downloaded and everything works as expected. (Maybe unnecessary, but: the model only has to be downloaded once. After that, it locates the model and doesn't re-download it for every run.) Then, I push the image to AWS ECR and load it into a lambda function. Now, when testing the function, it produces the following error:

```
[ERROR] OSError: Can't load config for 'sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6'. Make sure that:
- 'sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'
- or 'sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json file
```

As the error indicates, it says it can't find the pre-trained model on the website. This is a different behaviour than when running the container locally. Also, it doesn't really make sense, since the model initialization script already downloaded the model to the image, so this shouldn't be necessary anymore. I guess that it first checks if the model is available online and then checks if it isn't already downloaded, but I'm not sure... Does anyone know how this different behaviour can be explained and how I can resolve this issue? The code (standard code, copied from the model's website, with `model_no` being either 0 or 1):

```
def summarizer(text, model_no):
    models = ['google/pegasus-cnn_dailymail', 'sshleifer/distilbart-cnn-12-6']
    model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(models[model_no])
    tokenizer = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained(models[model_no])
    inputs = tokenizer([text], max_length=1024, return_tensors='pt')
    summary_ids = model.generate(inputs['input_ids'], num_beams=4, max_length=5, early_stopping=True)
    return [tokenizer.decode(g, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False) for g in summary_ids]
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated!
Pieter

Comment: I suggest focusing on the differences of the AWS Lambda runtime environment versus your local environment, instead of focusing on ECR. For example, did you configure the Lambda function to run inside a VPC? ECR is just file storage, the runtime environment is where the differences are.

Comment: @MarkB Thank you for your suggestion. I'm not really familiar with runtime environment differences, nor with the concept of VPCs. Could you perhaps point me in the right direction on how to solve this? Should I configure my lambda function to run inside a VPC for example? Any guidance is very welcome!

Comment: No, configuring it in a VPC without understanding the implications would be one reason for this type of issue. If it's not running in a VPC then that is good. Did you follow [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html) for building a container that will run in Lambda? Like implementing the Lambda runtime API in the container? If you are just trying to run a standard docker container in the cloud you may be better off using ECS+Fargate instead of Lambda.

Comment: @MarkB Yes I did follow the documentation. I forgot to mention that the error displayed before the error described in the post is the following: `[Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'`. When I search for this error I get something about Lambda only being able to read from (or write to?) the `/tmp` folder. Do you think this might have something to do with it? And if so, how I can solve this? Again, I'm a complete beginner in Docker and AWS. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Yes that is absolutely one of those Lambda runtime differences that you will need to deal with. You can't write to that home directory when running in AWS Lambda, you can only write to the `/tmp` directory.

Comment: @MarkB I see. What do you suggest? Should I manually download the model in an initialization script to the `/tmp` directory of the docker image? How do I do this correctly? And then call it like `model = BartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('/tmp/models/...')`? I'm lost to be honest, after being stuck for a week... Please let me know how you think I can solve this best. Kind regards.

Comment: @pieterhop Any luck with this issue. I have been stuck for hours now.

Comment: @pieterhop @Nikhil I am also trying to push a docker container as a lambda function. However, I have already downloaded the trained model in a folder and containerized it. 

I am able to test my function locally. But lambda throws an error where it is not able to read the saved_model.pb file or tokenizer from the ```/models/``` folder. 

Were you able to solve this issue?